# Thread Pool blocks main threads after some loops

Tags: c++, multithreading, threadpool

I'm trying to learn how threading works on C++ and I found an implementation which I used as a guide 
to make my own implementation, however after a loop or a couple it blocks.

I have a thread-safe queue in which I retrieve the jobs that are assigned to the thread pool.

Each thread runs this function:

```
// Declarations
std::vector<std::thread> m_threads;
JobQueue m_jobs; // A queue with locks
std::mutex m_mutex;
std::condition_variable m_condition;
std::atomic_bool m_active;
std::atomic_bool m_started;
std::atomic_int m_busy;
///...

[this, threadIndex] {
    int numThread = threadIndex;

    while(this->m_active) {
        std::unique_ptr<Job> currJob;
        bool dequeued = false;
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock { this->m_mutex };
            this->m_condition.wait(lock, [this, numThread]() {
                return (this->m_started && !this->m_jobs.empty()) || !this->m_active;
            });
            if (this->m_active) {
                m_busy++;
                dequeued = this->m_jobs.dequeue(currJob);
            }
        }

        if (dequeued) {
            currJob->execute();
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock { this->m_mutex };
                m_busy--;
            }
            m_condition.notify_all();
        } else {
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock { this->m_mutex };
                m_busy--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the loop is basically:

```
while(1) {
        int numJobs = rand() % 10000;
        std::cout << "Will do " << numJobs << " jobs." << std::endl;
        while(numJobs--) {
            pool.assign([](){
                // some heavy calculation
             });
        }
        pool.waitEmpty();
        std::cout << "Done!" << std::endl; // chrono removed for readability
    }
```

While the `waitEmpty` method is described as:

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock { this->m_mutex };
this->m_condition.wait(lock, [this] {
    return this->empty();
});
```

And is in this wait method that the code usually hangs as the test inside is never called again.

I've debugged it, changed the notification_one's and all's from place to place, but for some reason after some loops it always blocks.

Usually, but not always, it locks on `condition_variable.wait()` method that locks the current thread until there are no other thread working and the queue is empty, but I also saw it happen when I call `condition_variable.notify_all()`.

Some debugging helped me notice that while I call `notify_all()` on the slave thread, the `wait()` in the main thread is not tested again.

The expected behavior is that it does not block when it loops.

I'm using `G++ 8.1.0` on `Windows`.

and the output is:

```
Will do 41 jobs.  
Done! Took 0ms!   
Will do 8467 jobs.


<main thread blocked>
```

**Edit:** I fixed the issue pointed by paddy's comment: now `m_busy--` also happens when a job is not dequeued.

**Edit 2:** Running this on Linux does not locks the main thread and runs as expected. (`g++ (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0`)

**Edit 3:** As mentioned in the comments, corrected `deadlock` to `block`, as it only involves one lock

**Edit 4:** As commented by [Jérôme Richard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60381357/1354228) I was able to improve it by creating a `lock_guard` around the `m_busy--;` but now the code blocks at the `notify_all()` that is called inside the assign method. Here is the assign method for reference:

```
template<class Func, class... Args>
    auto assign(Func&& func, Args&&... args) -> std::future<typename std::result_of<Func(Args...)>::type> {
        using jobResultType = typename std::result_of<Func(Args...)>::type;

        auto task = std::make_shared<std::packaged_task<jobResultType()>>(
            std::bind(std::forward<Func>(func), std::forward<Args>(args)...)
        );

        auto job = std::unique_ptr<Job>(new Job([task](){ (*task)(); }));
        std::future<jobResultType> result = task->get_future();

        m_jobs.enqueue(std::move(job));
        std::cout << " - enqueued";
        m_condition.notify_all();
        std::cout << " - ok!" << std::endl;

        return result;
    }
```

In one of the loops the last output is

```
//...
 - enqueued - ok!
 - enqueued - ok!
 - enqueued

<blocked again>
```

**Edit 5:** With the latest changes, this does not happens on `msbuild` compiler.

The Gist for my implementation is here: https://gist.github.com/GuiAmPm/4be7716b7f1ea62819e61ef4ad3beb02

Here's also the original Article which I based my implementation:
https://roar11.com/2016/01/a-platform-independent-thread-pool-using-c14/

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your question to contain [mcve] with source code as text in your question. Please read the article which explains why it is important to do so https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: A deadlock usually involves more than one lock. You're going to need to include the relevant code in the question here.

Comment: The thing that stands out for me is that your thread workers increment `m_busy` and then do `dequeued = this->m_jobs.dequeue(currJob)`, but they _only_ decrement busy if `dequeued` is true.  So the operation is not symmetric.  Since your condition-wait relies on `m_busy` becoming zero, maybe start looking there.  Beyond this, replace all your locks with your own lock-guard that displays a message on acquire and release, so you can see what's going on.

Comment: @paddy Indeed I missed that in the example, but fixing that didn't resolve the issue. Thanks.

Comment: @Slava Did the changes improve the question?

Comment: A deadlock *always* involves more than one lock, acquired in different orders in different threads. No evidence of that here. What you have is just a block. @tadman

Comment: @user207421 For a true deadlock, yes, but other languages report a "deadlock" when the lock times out, more akin to a block. I don't know why they use that phrasing.

Comment: @tadman Me neither. Let's not misuse standard terminology.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: use a `std::lock_guard` of `m_mutex` around `m_busy--` to avoid unexpected wait condition blocking.

### Analysis

First of all, please note that the problem can occur with one thread in the pool and just few jobs. This means that there is a problem between the master thread that submit the jobs and the one that execute them.
Using GDB to analyze further the state of the program when the wait condition get stuck, one can see that there is no jobs, `m_busy` is set to 0 and both threads are waiting for notifications.
This means that there is a concurrency issue on the wait condition between the master and the only worker on the last job to execute.
By adding a global atomic clock in your code, one can see that (in almost all case)  the worker finishes all the jobs before the master can wait for the jobs to be completed and workers done.

Here is one practical scenario retrieved (bullets are done sequentially):

- the master start the wait call and there is jobs remaining
- the worker perform `m_busy++`, dequeue the last job and execute it (`m_busy` is now set to 1 and the job queue is empty)
- the master compute the predicate of the wait call
- the master call `ThreadPool::empty` and the result is false due to `busy` set to 1
- the worker perform `m_busy--` (`m_busy` is now set to 0)
- from that moment, the master could wait for the condition back (but is *suspected* to not do it)
- the worker notify the condition
- the master is *suspected* to wait for the condition back only now and to not be impacted by this last notification (as no waits will happen next)
- At this point, the master is no longer executing instructions and will wait forever
- the worker wait for the condition and will wait forever too

The fact that the master is not impacted by the notification is very strange.
It seems to be related to memory fencing issues. A more detailed explanation can be found [here](https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/c-core-guidelines-be-aware-of-the-traps-of-condition-variables). To quote the article:

> Even if you make dataReady an atomic, it must be modified under the mutex; if not the modification to the waiting thread may be published, but not correctly synchronized.

So a solution is to replace the `m_busy--` instruction by the following lines:

```
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck {this->m_mutex};
    m_busy--;
}
```

It avoid the previous scenario. Indeed, on one hand `m_mutex` is acquired in during the predicate checking of the `wait` call preventing `m_busy` to be modified during this specific moment; on the other hand it enforce data to be properly synchronized.

It should be theoretically safer to also include the `m_jobs.dequeue` call into it but will strongly reduce the degree of parallelism of the workers. In practice, useful synchronizations are made when the lock is released in the worker threads.

Please note that one general workaround to avoid such problems could be to add a timeout to waiting calls using the `wait_for` function in a loop to enforce the predicate condition. However, this solution comes a the price of a higher latency of the waiting calls and can thus significantly slow the execution down.

Comment: That is a really nice explanation, thanks for that, but it didn't fix it completely (it now run for longer before locking, though). I noticed that now it stucks on the `m_condition.notify_all();` line inside the assign method.

Comment: I've added the code for this piece of code I mentioned.